# Why can't I set state value (default value is current location if I allow location permission) after I allowed location permission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have select options collection of cities. Default selected value is current location if i allow. But after i allowed location permission, can't select another value. So, i can select another city for one second and set state current city again.

navigation geolocation code:

```
   const useCurrentLocation = () => {
    
      // store location in state
      const [location, setLocation] = useState();
    
      // Success handler for geolocation's `getCurrentPosition` method
      const handleSuccess = (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    
        setLocation({
          latitude,
          longitude
        });
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
          return false;
        }
        // Call the Geolocation API
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleSuccess);
      }, []);
    
      // Expose location result
      return { location };
    };
    export default useCurrentLocation;
```

find nearest city according to location coordinates and set loc code:

```
function Nearest({ loc, setLoc }) {
  const { location } = useCurrentLocation();
  const { city } = useCity();

  location && NearestCity(location.latitude, location.longitude);

  // Convert Degress to Radians
  function Deg2Rad(deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI) / 180;
  }

  function PythagorasEquirectangular(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    lat1 = Deg2Rad(lat1);
    lat2 = Deg2Rad(lat2);
    lon1 = Deg2Rad(lon1);
    lon2 = Deg2Rad(lon2);
    var R = 6371; // km
    var x = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos((lat1 + lat2) / 2);
    var y = lat2 - lat1;
    var d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y) * R;
    return d;
  }

  function NearestCity(latitude, longitude) {
    var minDif = 99999;
    var closest;
    var dif;

    city.map((item, index) => {
      dif = PythagorasEquirectangular(latitude, longitude, item.lat, item.lon);
      if (dif < minDif) {
        closest = index;
        minDif = dif;
      }
    });

    setLoc(city[closest]);
  }

  //select city
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    var index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    setLoc(city[index]);
  };
```

return select options:

```
<select value={loc.name} onChange={handleChange}>
        {city.map((val, i) => (
          <option id={i} key={i} value={val.name}>
            {val.name} - {i}
          </option>
        ))}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem!

the solution is putting NearestCity inside a useEffect that is triggered by location.

```
useEffect(() => {
    location && NearestCity(location.latitude, location.longitude);
  }, [location]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the value to your react state, you've made it a [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

One solution would be to export `setLocation` from your `useCurrentLocation` hook and use that instead of your `setLoc` (or call both if you need `setLoc`).

Another approach could be to use [defaultvalue (uncontrolled input)](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).